# Filter on an object with an array inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So, struggling a little with this one.

I have an object which looks like this:

```
const search = something.map((some) => {
  const search = {
    writer: some.writers, // (this is an array)
    title: some.title.toLowerCase(),
    reference: some.reference.toLowerCase(),
  };
  return search;
});
```

I am trying to do a search on all the text inside the values of the object.
The `some.writer` field is an array that can have numerous writers inside.

I am currently filtering through like this:

```
const filtered = search.filter((entry) => Object.values(entry).some((val) => typeof val === 'string'
&& val.includes(searchTerm)));
```

That filter looks for the search term inside the object and returns all strings which contain the term or part of the term.

The problem is, it only looks at the top level and does not go inside the `writers` array to search inside there too.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is writers an array of object or primitive values. Also are you simply looking for a string in any property or some specific?

Comment: Are you looking **only** for exact matches, or for substring matches too?

Answer (score 3):

See below for an option where you don't need the `search` array (provided you're doing full-string matches, not substrings), but if you keep the `search` array then When building it from the `something` array, I'd also make all the writers lower case (and I'd use [`toLocaleLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) for locale-awareness in the "to lower" operation):

```
const search = something.map((some) => {
    const entry = {
        writer: some.writers.map(writer => writer.toLocaleLowerCase()),
        title: some.title.toLocaleLowerCase(),
        reference: some.reference.toLocaleLowerCase(),
    };
    return entry;
});
```

Then when filtering, instead of building a bunch of intermediate arrays, I'd search more directly:

```
// I'm assuming `val` has already been put through `toLocaleLowerCase`
const filtered = search.filter(({title, reference, writers}) => {
    return title === val || reference === val || writers.includes(val);
});
```

But if you want to make it dynamic so adding new properties to the entries works without modifying the search code (other than when you create `search`), then as has been pointed out in comments, you can use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array of values so `writers` is spread out into the top level of the array:

```
// I'm assuming `val` has already been put through `toLocaleLowerCase`
const filtered = search.filter(entry => Object.values(entry).flat().includes(val));
```

Both are fairly simple to tweak to make substring searches:

```
// I'm assuming `val` has already been put through `toLocaleLowerCase`
const filtered = search.filter(({title, reference, writers}) => {
    return title.includes(val) || reference.includes(val) || writers.some(writer => writer.includes(val));
});
```

and

```
// I'm assuming `val` has already been put through `toLocaleLowerCase`
const filtered = search.filter(entry => Object.values(entry).flat().some(e => e.includes(val)));
```

---

You might also want to use [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) on the search values and `val` to handle discrepancies in the different ways some "characters" can be represented in Unicode. If so, basically change all the `.toLocaleLowerCase()` above to `.normalize().toLocaleLowerCase()`.

---

If you're doing exact matches, you can avoid having to create the `search` array and doing all those `toLowerCase`/`toLocaleLowerCase` calls. This also has the advantage that the search results have the text in its original form. To do that you'd use an [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) object telling it that you want case-insensitive matching via the [`sensitivity` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#:%7E:text=default%20is%20%22sort%22.-,sensitivity,-Which%20differences%20in):

```
const {compare} = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
    sensitivity: "accent" // Or you might want `"base"`
});
const match = (a, b) => compare(a, b) === 0);
const filtered = something.filter(({title, reference, writers}) => {
    return match(title, val) || match(reference, val) || writers.some(writer => match(writer, val));
});
```

Comment: What an incredible and well thought out answer, thank you @T.J Crowder

Comment: I am including substrings, so if the user types hel -> hello, help etc would all match. Flattening does not really help as the problem is the top level object is fine, but the writers array inside is a step in and a bit difficult to search inside. The users can only be from one locale, so no need to match on locale.

Comment: @ZackAmin - I'm not sure I'm following the thrust of that comment...? The above shows how to do substring matching. Have I made a mistake somewhere in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to turn something like `[1, [2, 3], 4]` into `[1, 2, 3, 4]`:

```js
const filtered = search.filter((entry) => Object.values(entry).flat().some((val) => typeof val === 'string' && val.includes(searchTerm)));
//                                                            ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is the top level is an object, with an array inside. I can search through the object but not a level down inside the array, so flattening it does not really help. Thank you.

Comment: Why? For `{writers:['a', 'b'], title:'c', reference:'d'}`, `Object.values` gave you `[['a', 'b'], 'c', 'd']` which is why searching writers failed. After flattening, you get `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, so I don't see why that wouldn't help, can you elaborate?

Comment: @ZackAmin - `Object.values` gives you the values of the properties of the object, say `[["william strunk jr.", "e.b. white"], "the elements of style", "oclc878906498"]`. If you flatten that, the writers array's elements are moved to the top level, so you get `["william strunk jr.", "e.b. white", "the elements of style", "oclc878906498"]`. Doing `.some(entry => entry.includes(val))` works on that array.

Comment: Object.values is returning me {writers: ['name']
reference: "utf/000165/2021"
title: "test report"

Comment: I think that's what `Object.values(search)` returns... not e.g. `Object.values(search[0])`. Don't forget you have the `Object.values` inside of a `filter` call and you are operating on each object (`entry`) in the `search` array and not on the `search` array itself...